# Nodejs mongodb driver Partial update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm learning mongodb, and after spend hours trying to find some information I failed, and that is the reason I'm asking this question here.

I'm wondering how can I update my array of documents in better way if possible.

If I do something like this

```
    const res = await collection.updateOne(
            { name: profile.name, 'links._id': olid },
            {
                $set: { 'links.$': data, },
            },
        );
```

All fields that is undefined in data will remove that field from document.

```
async updateLink(profile: Profile, link: Link, data: IUpdateLinkDataDTO): Promise<void> {
        const database = await this.repo.getDb();
        const collection = database.collection('profiles');

        const olid = new ObjectId(link.id);

        const res = await collection.updateOne(
            { name: profile.name, 'links._id': olid },
            {
                $set: {
                    'links.$.label': data.label || link.label,
                    'links.$.media': data.media || link.media,
                    'links.$.action': data.action || link.action,
                    'links.$.hide': data.hide || link.hide,
                    'links.$.index': data.index || link.index,
                },
            },
        );

        console.log(res.modifiedCount);
    }
```

So I found this solution, which is basically check if the field exists on data otherwise I send the "old" information again to preserve the fields.

Is there a better way?

As @prakash-harvani suggested, I know that I can do something like he said or even a loop on Object.entries like

```js
const values: any = {};
Object.entries(data).forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry[1] !== undefined) {
        values[`links.$.${entry[0]}`] = entry[1];
    }
});
```

But I would like to know, if is there any kind of mongo operator to do that for me.

Mongo has a lot of configuration and operators, and I expected that some operator could take care of this for me, my mongodb versions is 4.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is one another way, try like this.

```
let updateData = { };
// for label
if(data && data.label && data.label!=undefined){
updateData['links.$.label'] =data.label;
}
// for media
if(data && data.media && data.media!=undefined){
updateData['links.$.media'] =data.media;
}
// for action
if(data && data.action && data.action!=undefined){
updateData['links.$.action'] =data.action;
}
// for hide
if(data && data.hide && data.hide!=undefined){
updateData['links.$.hide'] =data.hide;
}
// index
if(data && data.index && data.index!=undefined){
updateData['links.$.index'] =data.index;
}

    const res = await collection.updateOne(
        { name: profile.name, 'links._id': olid },
        {
            $set: updateData,
        },
    );
```

it's a better way to do this type of stuff